# Upload file to AWS S3 using presigned URL via Spring webclient error: "the Credential is mal-formed"

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, pre-signed-url

I'm using reactive spring and trying to upload a ".csv" file into AWS S3 using a presigned URL.

I spring webclient for this and my code snippet as below

**Webclient bean**

```
@Bean

public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider
    .builder("customFixedConnectionPool").maxConnections(maxConnections).pendingAcquireTimeout(
        Duration.ofMillis(acquireTimeout)).build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider).resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);

return webClientBuilder
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))

    .build(); }
```

**FileUploadClient.java**

**Note:** in below, `BodyInserters.fromResource(resource)` returns  `BodyInserter<Resource, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage>`

```
@Component
public class FileUploadClient implements FileUploadClientInterface {

  public FileUploadClient(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient.mutate()
        .build();
  }

  private final WebClient webClient;

  @Override
  public Mono<FileUploadResponse> uploadFIle(String preSignedUrl, String filePath) {

    Resource resource = new PathResource(filePath);


    return webClient.put()
        .uri(preSignedUrl)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {


          if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)) {

            fileUploadResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
            fileUploadResponse.setMessage("FILE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS");

            return Mono.just(fileUploadResponse);
          } else {

            return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .flatMap(responseBodyString -> {

                  fileUploadResponse.setCode(response.statusCode().value());
                  fileUploadResponse.setMessage(responseBodyString);

                  return Mono.just(fileUploadResponse);
                });
          }
        }).onErrorResume(throwable -> {
          fileUploadResponse.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
          fileUploadResponse.setMessage(throwable.getMessage());
          System.out.println("uploadLog Error: "+ throwable.getMessage());
          return Mono.just(fileUploadResponse);
        });

  }
}
```

`

When executing, I receive below error:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code><Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "&lt;YOUR-AKID&gt;/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".</Message><RequestId>xxxxxx</RequestId><HostId>xxxxxx</HostId></Error>`

Presigned URL i use has below like format:

```
https://xxx-xx-xxx-xx.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/PG00009912/PENDING/REQ_PG00009912_11112022.csv?X-Amz-Security-Token=dzEIz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDLAplr5Vvi%2F0mZqIMSLABMetINeSCoOWcMxBPkBQN44hB1gyNBFfSPoAOLe0FY8lhBgsBis%2F7oRp3WU8H6qDUpI%2BsxCZEIFMWTkoP%2FIZP%2FAUG5ib8qAIx3gCuVtFLLx77kxdclqm8PhC6OlkYZ5fBrlUl7hHvY9w8hdFAWvRByaqsNKGWiiwwhaMvWZNI65O%2BoWZ84ESwBQCZxbp3e4TdWvUEuB%2FnVpyoMbUfugGxVK2rG58rgJpUKK5E9rv8ZTzIkUqjH7Ql5ZL%2FCt0%2FTa%2Fbj98617MKMk2bPu7dcLZpurNJ75J4AIH2a5%2Bql5tk7FB2f8uwIad3ZskiV5rtz%2FmyoqxFxc5eaaC6YbXDC06eHcMirg81U15XXqFgM2Qi%2FFjx3yutm0E59aPHSEz1K0ucfe2%2FUYLYbB57V%2FgFD8MO8pwHKmLDC0hXVFhXny8nnpPq5PBkqzZomk%2BBOiwBnkP5H98tRXRshwhqnmIMh80xyEy6%2FfCLBRSmJEMrzTpQqDpi%2B1%2Fg7wnOK8Gpv2iyLIU%2FBTD1%2FwgQ716qVsDjH8eTyPga513G6uZ94Kp4pKr1M1E1wsh2IbuvfMlPQ%2FOnL7zA07jZtNxWe%2B538Gs5%2FMwtz9fM%2FoEkeNolx96k3cgDCyQCiD8HU%2FKJk8UYUttSv8CBwkI3PwAW1Sdty0O2L0dGGyFFwwtu6wql8%2BJYxkAZOdZCxDDg2YoaeayVrjYq9mp9yZ%2BxJR1OsVuwmfRkQZcgkUPj7MnCGdgKN1KJAiNk6uVs%2FpSRxEWtSeJlhU806%2FACCiznbObBjIrEwg1WuV%2BkReFAoD86rDec%2BE%2BKmhjb2ahFqHqtY9V4YAYF82RtEzUQld6MQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20221110T101307Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=26212&X-Amz-Credential=H2DP6FQ%2F20221110%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=787c80356d749c9e0e1231ceb75d64df77f1cf40830146dfa
```

I'm using Java 1.8 on Windows platform and I don't set any headers in my webclient .

**Update (Solution)**

Issue was due to webclient has further encoded my presigned url which is unnecessary. Fixed by using `.uri(URI.create(preSignedUrl))` instead of just `.uri(preSignedUrl)`.

Comment: Considering you're using Java 1.8, I'm assuming this is a pretty old application. In that case, can I ask which region the URL is for? Is the URL being generated by this same Java 1.8 application too?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added a sample presigned URL for your reference

Comment: OK so that's a Sig V4 URL - does it work when using the AWS CLI etc.? Can you confirm the link is fully valid?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I was able to upload a csv using postman without any issue

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary presigned URL generator application has developed in Java 11

Comment: We need more code around the webclient and the entire class - do you have something reproducible? What's the value of `BodyInserters.fromResource(resource)`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary added information on webclient Bean and return type of BodyInserters.fromResource(resource) to the original question

Comment: Was able to fix the issue. More info included to the question description