Autodesk Model Derivative API upload file to oss failing
Integrating Autodesk (APS) Model Derivative API's in Java project. Upload file to oss step is failing with error as below:

400 Bad Request: "


AuthorizationQueryParametersError
Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "<YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".

ETG6XQTC4WQ1EM86
MABuAzYxu3R/clTqPqXBF/o7h/u/m3UsVeKa0sdEciYNzpOd91RKl5xsJ8xwVhF4R8Sf/GG4cSgnne7mItPVmycmSLomQTJnXmd80UVVJvY=
"

API reference: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/#step-3-upload-the-file
This api uses endpoint received in earlier step "Obtain signed url". If I try to upload file using this signedurl through postman then it works but it fails through code.
Tried using headers.set("Content-Type", "application/zip"); as well as octet stream

Fails with RestTemplate but succeeds with HttpURLConnection. What could be the reason?

Looks like issue related to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389361/upload-file-to-aws-s3-using-presigned-url-via-spring-webclient-error-the-crede

@Carol Sharing code snippet
// Read the file into a byte array
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);

// Set headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

// Create the HTTP entity
HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, headers);

// Execute the PUT request
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
    signedUrl,
    HttpMethod.PUT,
    entity,
    String.class
);

if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
   return "Upload successful!";
} else {
   return "Upload failed: " + response.getStatusCode();
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Couple of things to note:

The correct format for the X-Amz-Credentialparameter is: <YOUR-AKID>/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request Where:
<YOUR-AKID> is your AWS Access Key ID. Eg: ASIAYZTHFNX5W7ZW3DKP
YYYYMMDD is the date in the format year, month, and day.
REGION is the AWS region you are targeting (e.g., us-west-2).
SERVICE is the AWS service you are making the request to (e.g., s3).


When you pass the X-Amz-Credential in Postman you will notice that the / in the X-Amz-Credential is escaped, so X-Amz-Credential <YOUR-AKID>/20240827/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request is sent as <YOUR-AKID>%2F20240827%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request.

So ensure in your code that the X-Amz-Credential is escaped using Uri.EscapeDataString(credentialParameter)


Alternatively, you can use the Autodesk.OSS SDK to upload the model and Autodesk.ModelDerivative to Translate the model. The Simple Viewer shows an example. Follow the UploadModel in Aps.Oss.cs and TranslateModel in APS.Deriv.cs. This way you don't have to deal with signed url and other headers etc.
